# Changing from FileInfo to XElement and needing to stream the data

Tags: c#, xml, streamwriter, xelement, fileinfo

My old signature was

```
protected override bool SendFiles(ITransactionStep configuration, FileInfo xml)
```

Thus I was working with doing this

```
using (var blobStream = GetBlobStream(arg.Configuration, arg.WorkspaceContext, arg.TempFile.Length, out var blob))
using (var tempData = xml.OpenRead())
```

However now I am switching from FileInfo to XElement

```
protected override bool SendFiles(ITransactionStep configuration, XElement xml)
```

Goal is to stream in the XElement and Write to fileshare

Thus I cannot use this

```
xml.OpenRead())  // Can't do that
```

Should I be doing an Steam .. . with  xmlstreamwriter or   streamwriter or streamreader?    How can I stream this XElement into memory to write to a fileshare ?

Comment: `XElement` is already completely in memory.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview): *LINQ to XML provides an **in-memory** XML programming interface that leverages the .NET Language-Integrated Query (LINQ) Framework. LINQ to XML uses .NET capabilities and is comparable to an updated, redesigned Document Object Model (DOM) XML programming interface.*  But perhaps you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) here, maybe you can explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: Ok - yes true it is already in memory - So I need to write that XElement to blobstorage ,   the old code  arg.TempFile.OpenRead()  which is essentially  FilePath.OpenRead()  , but essentially the  xml.OpenRead() is not a method -  so if I'm wanting to take this XElement and stream it to fileshare  -  all these old methods and properties for FileInfo like   .Length,   .OpenRead() ,  .CopyTo(blobStream)  are needing replaced

Comment: Then can you please [edit] your question to make it clear what you are asking?  Is your question, *How can I [save](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.save?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_Save_System_IO_Stream_) an `XElement` to a `Stream`?*  Or is it something else?

Comment: Ok - yes  that is what I think I want to do.   It was that I was switching some existing code out and trying to backfill it / retro fit  with the new change.

Comment: Then you can use [`Save()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.save?view=net-5.0#System_Xml_Linq_XElement_Save_System_IO_Stream_) or [`SaveAsync()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement.saveasync?view=net-5.0).